# undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class on view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My code is working on local server but it's not working on the production server. I can't figure it out what I'm doing wrong.Please help me.

This is where I'm getting error in my partial:

```
 <%=form_for @shiftchange, :url => { :controller=>"schedulers" ,:action => "shift_change" },:validate=>true , :method => :post do |f|%>

       <%= f.label :from_date , "From Date " %>
       <%= f.text_field :from_date ,:class =>'datepicker' %>
   <% end %>
```

To load the partial,this is what I'm doing this:-

```
<%= render "schedule_shift" %>
```

In the controller I have this:

```
@shiftchange = Shiftchange.new
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting in the production server ?

Comment: @AmitThawait undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
form_for @shiftchange
```

for this

```
form_for :shiftchange
```

i guess it works

Comment: Now its giving me this error ActionView::Template::Error (Using form_for(:name, @resource) is not supported with ClientSideValidations. Please use form_for(@resource, :as => :name) instead.):

Answer (score 0):

If the form is included for multiple actions (pages) you need to set @shiftchange to something or the form_for directive will fail (it won't have anything to create a form for).

A much better approach (and the Rails default) is to have separate views for each action, each including only the elements required by that action, and loaded into your `application.html.erb` layout with `<%= yield %>.` So you would have a `app/views/shiftchanges/new.html.erb` view which has the form in it. You never very rarely need to define any load paths in Rails, they are all derived from the `model, controller and action` names - or from your `routes.rb`. This is a core part of the `convention over configuration`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration paradigm which runs so deep in Rails.

If you do need to have a form for creating a new object on every page (often used for ShiftchangeSessions for example), you can rewrite your form_for so that it doesn't depend on an object being present:

```
form_for(Shiftchange.new)
```

or if you need to force it to post to the create method

```
form_for(Shiftchange.new, :url => { :action => "create" })
```

You can read more about resource driven `form_for` in the Ruby On Rails API docs http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for-label-Resource-oriented+style.